# How to integrate between two different angular applications

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular 7.
I have separated login module into one application and remaining into other application and i am loading login application first if the login is success i have to navigate to second application.
Kindly let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your question it's not clear if you wish to merge these projects or host them separately.

As i see it you have two options:

1. [Merge the projects](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527) and route as normal to the "second application". And handle the login state using [guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)
2. Host the projects separately. You would still be able to store login state locally per client and handle it with guards on the second application. You could then simply route to the other web page after logging in.

If there are any questions regarding routing, please read the [docs](https://angular.io/docs)

Comment: i would like to separate the login module into one project and remaining into new project. after success full login second project should be load into browser.

Comment: @Santhosh This would be possible to do. I'd say either try [sharing LocalStorage](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384). Or once the user is authorized you could pass the user token in the url (once you navigate to the second project, pass it as parameter)